# IDEA database adding

Tags: intellij-idea

Why I dont have buttons for adding database like on the screenshot? All pugins are enabled.

[image]

Comment: Have you double-checked that you have the same version as the screen shot?  I don't see database buttons in my version either, I am using IntelliJ 11.1.3.  I do have a "Data Sources" button on the toolbar that is docked to the right side of the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88255) in IDEA 12.0 release. It will be fixed in the next update. Right now you can right click inside the `Database` tool window and add data sources from the context menu.

[image: Add]

Comment: Tnx a lot. But I also can not add database with context menu. I have only "rename" "compare" and diagrams buttons there.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?